# Целое число в строку без экспоненты

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, biginteger, bigdecimal

У меня есть число `a=11**20` и мне нужно вывести его в строку.

Но `str(a)` не подходит так, как получится:

```
'6.727499949325601e+20'
```

, а мне нужно, чтобы было целое число без экспоненты:

```
'672749994932560009201'
```

Comment: не может такой вывод получиться для примера в вопросе. Покажите реальный пример числа. `str(11**20) == '672749994932560009201'`

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего у вас дробное число:

```
In [18]: str(11.0**20)
Out[18]: '6.727499949325601e+20'
```

чтобы указать нужный вам формат - воспользуйтесь форматированием строк:

```
In [19]: res = '{:.0f}'.format(11.0**20)

In [20]: res
Out[20]: '672749994932560068608'
```

Comment: `>>> print(123**33)
926549609804623448265268294182900512918058893428212027689876489708283`

Зачем тут `format`?

Comment: @Scarabyte, немного дополнил ответ...